# Hibernate Mappedby Example

Tags: java, hibernate

The Hibernate [Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html) (2.2.5.1. One-to-one) present the following example:

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="passport_fk")
    public Passport getPassport() {
        ...
    }

@Entity
public class Passport implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "passport")
    public Customer getOwner() {
    ...
}
```

As I understand, `Customer` has a one-to-one relationship with `Passport`, where `Customer` is the owner, i.e. responsible for cascading updates to `Passport`. The `mappedBy` in `Passport` indicates that it has a one-to-one relationship with `Customer`, but it is not responsible for cascading updates to `Customer`.

`Customer` has a foreign-key constraint on `Passport`, as well as vice-versa for `Passport` to `Customer`.

What is the meaning of the `@JoinColumn(name="passport_fk")` of `Customer`? How about `passport` in the `mappedBy` of `Passport`? Are they the table columns representing their respective foreign keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
What is the meaning of the @JoinColumn(name="passport_fk") of Customer?
```

This means that passport_fk field will be created inside Customer table, since it *belongs* here, this table is treated as the owner of the relationship (you seem to get that though).

```
 How about passport in the mappedBy of Passport
```

Since this is annotated with *mappedBy* it shows that this si NOT the owner, and that the Owner is Customer (the field that is annotated). *name* attribute is telling Hibernate where to find the information about the FK mapping (inside Customer there is a getPassport method). No additional fields will be created in Passport.

Comment: So `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "passport")` means there's a 1-to-1 association, and that `Customer`'s `passport` field maps it(the passport)? Also, is it possible to create a Passport without an already existing Customer? In other words, does Passport have a fk to customer?

Comment: @KevinMeredith yes OneToOne means a 1-to-1, obvious. And no you can' t create a Child without a parent. Think about it at a DB level, since u do not have a PK already in the database, u can't insert a Child.

Comment: based on this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9108618/409976), then my understanding is that `Passport` would not have a foreign key constraint to `Customer`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith finally I has some time to re-read the question. As you have the mappings right you can insert both the child and parent alone without a problem, this is because Hibernate by default does not create a unique constraint on FK, they will simply be null. So even if you have a FK constraint it will not be enforced, unless, for example you put the optional=false on the OneToOne.