# Hibernate-JPA deleting in cascade or triggers

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA and Hibernate as provider with MySQL DBMS and I remarked that the cascade deleting does not work for my situation :

```
    @Entity
    public class Entity_1{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int id;
   private String nomAttribute;

   @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
   private java.util.List<Entity_2> et2;

   ...
   }
```

and the second Entity is

```
  @Entity
  public class Entity_2{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;
  private String nomAttribute;
    ...
  }
```

the result is a three tables

Entity_1 ,Entity_2, Entity_1_Entity_2

I remarked that when I delete a Entity_1 the Entity_2 is too deleted because of the cascade on deleting .

what I want is when I delete Entity_1 the relation between Entity_1 and Entity_2 deleted only not the Entity_2 and I tried Many options in but all in vain

**What the option should I use or there are no options for that and I should use Triggers ??**

Comment: No you don't need triggers, check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108224/can-someone-please-explain-mappedby-in-hibernate

Comment: they are not talking about cascade deleting ,they are talking about bidirectional relation,if not so could you specify where exactly plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What about this solution ?

**Class Entity1 :**

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE }, mappedBy = "entity1")
    private Collection<Entity1Entity2> collection;

    ...
}
```

**Class Entity2 :**

```
@Entity
public class Entity2 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE }, mappedBy = "entity2")
    private Collection<Entity1Entity2> collection;

    ...
}
```

**Class Entity1Entity2 (which is the join table) :**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(Entity1Entity2Pk.class)
public class Entity1Entity2 {

    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    private Entity1 entity1;

    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    private Entity2 entity2;

    ...    
}
```

**Class Entity1Entity2Pk (which is needed for `Entity1Entity2`) :**

```
public class Entity1Entity2Pk {

    private int entity1;

    private int entity2;

}
```

### Update :

I added `mappedBy = "entity1"` and `mappedBy = "entity2"`.
In that way `@oneToMany` associations won't create extra join tables.

Comment: supposing that this is a solution ,to implement this solution I have to change all my classes (I have a lot) and that will generate a great number of classes and tables, could you give me some other solutions it it's possible

Comment: @user3660257 This will not generate any more tables than using `@ManyToMany` like you have above.  In your example, JPA creates a table to represent the linkage of `@ManyToMany`.  In Basemasta's example, there is still a linking table, but he's managing it as an entity.  I **always** use this strategy instead of `@ManyToMany`.  One key reason is that most of the time, record linkages themselves are decorated with additional data, like "when was the linkage made?".  In this case, you simply add non-key fields to `Entity1Entity2`

Comment: @GlennLane according to what I saw in a tuto I had understand that oneToMany association also generate a third table for join the two entities isn't it ? [tuto](http://blog.paumard.org/cours/jpa/chap03-entite-relation.html#d0e1324)

Comment: Answer updated with mappedBy in @oneToMany associations. So those associations will not generate join tables.