# Hibernate One to many Annotation Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi I have a two tables like below .

1) Task - id,name
2) Resource - id,name,defaultTask(foreign key to Task.id)

The mapping is one to Many - one task can have many resource.

The code for Task is like below.

```
@Entity
public class Task implements Serializable {
private long m_id;
private String m_name;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(
    strategy = GenerationType.AUTO
)
public long getId() {
    return this.m_id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.m_id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.m_name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.m_name = name;
}

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(
    name = "defaultTask"
)
private List<Resource> m_relatedResources;

public List<Resource> getrelatedResources() {
    return m_relatedResources;
}


public void setrelatedResources(List<Resource> relatedResources) {
    m_relatedResources = relatedResources;
}
```

And the code for Resource class is like below.

```
@Entity
public class Resource implements Serializable {
private Long m_id;
private String m_name;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
    strategy = GenerationType.AUTO
)
public Long getId() {
    return this.m_id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.m_id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.m_name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.m_name = name;
}
Task m_task;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(
    name = "defaultTask"
)
public Task getTask() {
    return this.m_task;
}

public void setTask(Task task) {
    this.m_task = task;
}
```

}

When i execute it I am getting an error like

**Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(relatedResources)]**

What have i done wrong ?How can i fix the problem ?

Comment: your question has been solved by real timework.. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't apply annotations to methods or fields randomly. Normally, you should apply your annotations the same way as @Id..

In Task  class OneToMany should be like

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(
    name = "defaultTask"
)
public List<Resource> getrelatedResources() {
    return m_relatedResources;
}
```

Field access strategy (determined by @Id annotation). Put any JPA related annotation right above each method instead of field / property as for your id it is above method and it will get you away form exception.
Also there appears to be an issue with your bidrectional mapping metntioned by @PredragMaric so you need to use MappedBy which signals hibernate that the key for the relationship is on the other side. Click for a really good question on [Mapped by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108224/can-someone-please-explain-mappedby-in-hibernate).

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing annotating fields and getters in the same entity, you should move your @OneToMany to a getter

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(mappedBy = "task")
public List<Resource> getrelatedResources() {
    return m_relatedResources;
}
```

and yes, as the others mentioned, it should be `mappedBy = "task"`. I'll upvote this teamwork :)

Answer (score 3):

Many mistakes here:

1. you're annotating fields sometimes, and getters sometimes. Half of the annotation will be ignored: you must be consistent. It's one or the other.
2. You're not respecting the Java Bean naming conventions. The getter must be `getRelatedResources()`, not `getrelatedResources()`.
3. A bidirectional association must have an owner side and an inverse side. In a OneToMany, the One is always the inverse side. The mapping should thus be:

.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "defaultTask")
public Task getTask() {
    return this.m_task;
}
```

and

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "task")
public List<Resource> getRelatedResources() {
    return m_relatedResources;
}
```

I also strongly advise you to respect the Java naming conventions. Variables should be named `id` and `name`, not `m_id` and `m_name`. This is especially important if you choose to annotate fields.

Answer (score 2):

`@JoinColumn` is only used on owner's side of the relation, `ToOne` side, which is `Resource#task` in your case. On the other side you should use `mappedBy` attribute to specify bidirectional relation. Change your `Task#relatedResources` mapping to this

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "task")
private List<Resource> m_relatedResources;
```

Also, as @Viraj Nalawade noticed (and others, obviously), mapping annotations should be on fields **or** properties, whatever is used for `@Id` takes precedence. Either move `@Id` to field, or move `@OneToMany` to getter.