# Spring boot exception

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I have created a spring boot project, and firstful i have created two entities with their Repository and metier interfaces and a restController and every thing was going well

location class:

```
package com.agence.entitises;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Location implements Serializable{





    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private   Long  NumLocation;
  private Date DateCreation; 
  private String Categorie; 
  private String type;




  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="NUM_LOCAT")
  private Locataire locataire;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="NUM_CONTRATS")
  private Contrats contrats;



@ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="NUM_PERIODELOCATION")
  private PerieodeLocation periodeLocation;







public Location(Long numLocation, Date dateCreation, String categorie,
        String type, Locataire locataire, Contrats contrats,
        PerieodeLocation periodeLocation) {
    super();
    NumLocation = numLocation;
    DateCreation = dateCreation;
    Categorie = categorie;
    this.type = type;
    this.locataire = locataire;
    this.contrats = contrats;
    this.periodeLocation = periodeLocation;
}

public PerieodeLocation getPeriodeLocation() {
    return periodeLocation;
}
public void setPeriodeLocation(PerieodeLocation periodeLocation) {
    this.periodeLocation = periodeLocation;
}


public Locataire getLocataire() {
    return locataire;
}
public void setLocataire(Locataire locataire) {
    this.locataire = locataire;
}
public Location(Long numLocation, Date dateCreation, String categorie,
        String type) {
    super();
    NumLocation = numLocation;
    DateCreation = dateCreation;
    Categorie = categorie;
    this.type = type;
}
public Location() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public Long getNumLocation() {
    return NumLocation;
}
public void setNumLocation(Long numLocation) {
    NumLocation = numLocation;
}
public Date getDateCreation() {
    return DateCreation;
}
public void setDateCreation(Date dateCreation) {
    DateCreation = dateCreation;
}
public String getCategorie() {
    return Categorie;
}
public void setCategorie(String categorie) {
    Categorie = categorie;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
public Contrats getContrats() {
    return contrats;
}
public void setContrats(Contrats contrats) {
    this.contrats = contrats;
}

}
```

Locataire class:

```
package com.agence.entitises;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;


@Entity
public class Locataire implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long NumLocataire ;
    private Date dateCreation ; 
    private String raisonSociale ;
    private String nomLocataire ;
    private String prenomLocataire ;
    private String ville ;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="locataire")
    private List<Location> locations;





    public Locataire(Long numLocataire, Date dateCreation,
            String raisonSociale, String nomLocataire, String prenomLocataire,
            String ville, List<Location> locations) {
        super();
        NumLocataire = numLocataire;
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
        this.raisonSociale = raisonSociale;
        this.nomLocataire = nomLocataire;
        this.prenomLocataire = prenomLocataire;
        this.ville = ville;
        this.locations = locations;
    }
    public String getPrenomLocataire() {
        return prenomLocataire;
    }
    public void setPrenomLocataire(String prenomLocataire) {
        this.prenomLocataire = prenomLocataire;
    }
    public String getVille() {
        return ville;
    }
    public void setVille(String ville) {
        this.ville = ville;
    }
    public List<Location> getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }
    public void setLocations(List<Location> locations) {
        this.locations = locations;
    }



    public Locataire(Long numLocataire, Date dateCreation,
            String raisonSociale, String nomLocataire) {
        super();
        NumLocataire = numLocataire;
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
        this.raisonSociale = raisonSociale;
        this.nomLocataire = nomLocataire;
    }
    public Locataire() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Long getNumLocataire() {
        return NumLocataire;
    }
    public void setNumLocataire(Long numLocataire) {
        NumLocataire = numLocataire;
    }
    public Date getDateCreation() {
        return dateCreation;
    }
    public void setDateCreation(Date dateCreation) {
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
    }
    public String getRaisonSociale() {
        return raisonSociale;
    }
    public void setRaisonSociale(String raisonSociale) {
        this.raisonSociale = raisonSociale;
    }
    public String getNomLocataire() {
        return nomLocataire;
    }
    public void setNomLocataire(String nomLocataire) {
        this.nomLocataire = nomLocataire;
    }


}
```

the Repository Interfaces:

```
package com.agence.Dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.agence.entitises.Locataire;

public interface ILocataireRepository  extends JpaRepository<Locataire, Long>{

}


package com.agence.Dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.agence.entitises.Location;



public interface ILocationRepository extends  JpaRepository<Location, Long>   {

}
```

LocataireMetier

```
package com.agence.Metier;

import java.util.List;

import com.agence.entitises.Locataire;

public interface LocataireMetier  {

    public Locataire saveLocataire(Locataire locataire) ;
    public List<Locataire > listeLocataires();
}
```

LocataireMetierImpl:

```
package com.agence.Metier;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.agence.Dao.ILocataireRepository;
import com.agence.entitises.Locataire;

@Service
public class LocataireMetierImpl implements LocataireMetier{

    @Autowired
    private ILocataireRepository locataireRepository ;
    @Override
    public Locataire saveLocataire(Locataire locataire) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return locataireRepository.save(locataire);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Locataire> listeLocataires() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return locataireRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

LocataireMetier :

```
package com.agence.Metier;

import java.util.List;

import com.agence.entitises.Location;

public interface LocationMetier {
    public Location saveLocation(Location loc);
    public List<Location> listeLocation() ;

}
```

LocationMetierImpl:

```
package com.agence.Metier;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;



import com.agence.Dao.ILocationRepository;
import com.agence.entitises.Location;

@Service
public class LocationMetierImpl  implements LocationMetier{

    @Autowired
    private ILocationRepository clientRepository ;

    @Override
    public Location saveLocation(Location loc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return clientRepository.save(loc); 
    }

    @Override
    public List<Location> listeLocation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return clientRepository.findAll();
    }


}
```

The RestController:

```
package com.agence.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.agence.Metier.LocataireMetier;
import com.agence.Metier.LocationMetier;
import com.agence.entitises.Locataire;
import com.agence.entitises.Location;

@RestController
public class LocationRestService {

    @Autowired
    private LocationMetier locationMetier ;
    private LocataireMetier locataireMetier ;

    @RequestMapping(value="/Locations" ,method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Location saveLocation( @RequestBody  Location loc) {
        return locationMetier.saveLocation(loc);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/Locations" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Location> listeLocation() {
        return locationMetier.listeLocation();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/Locataires" ,method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Locataire saveLocataire( @RequestBody Locataire locataire) {
        return locataireMetier.saveLocataire( locataire);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/Locataires" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public List<Locataire> listeLocataires() {
            return locataireMetier.listeLocataires();
        }


    }
```

at this case everything works, but when i added the following entities:

Contrats:

```
package com.agence.entitises;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public   class Contrats  implements  Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long NumContrat ;
    private String EtatContrat ; 
    private Date dateCreation ;
    private String referencePeriode ; 
    private String referenceLocataire ;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="Contrats")
    private List<Location> locations;


    public Contrats(Long numContrat, String etatContrat, Date dateCreation) {
        super();
        NumContrat = numContrat;
        EtatContrat = etatContrat;
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
    }
    public List<Location> getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }
    public void setLocations(List<Location> locations) {
        this.locations = locations;
    }
    public Long getNumContrat() {
        return NumContrat;
    }
    public void setNumContrat(Long numContrat) {
        NumContrat = numContrat;
    }
    public String getEtatContrat() {
        return EtatContrat;
    }
    public void setEtatContrat(String etatContrat) {
        EtatContrat = etatContrat;
    }
    public Date getDateCreation() {
        return dateCreation;
    }
    public void setDateCreation(Date dateCreation) {
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
    }
    public String getReferencePeriode() {
        return referencePeriode;
    }
    public void setReferencePeriode(String referencePeriode) {
        this.referencePeriode = referencePeriode;
    }
    public String getReferenceLocataire() {
        return referenceLocataire;
    }
    public void setReferenceLocataire(String referenceLocataire) {
        this.referenceLocataire = referenceLocataire;
    }
    public Contrats() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Contrats(Long numContrat, String etatContrat, Date dateCreation,
            String referencePeriode, String referenceLocataire) {
        super();
        NumContrat = numContrat;
        EtatContrat = etatContrat;
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
        this.referencePeriode = referencePeriode;
        this.referenceLocataire = referenceLocataire;
    }
```

}

PriodeLocation:

```
package com.agence.entitises;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;


@Entity
public class PerieodeLocation  implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long numPeriode ;



    private Long ReferenceLocation ;
    private Date dateDebut ;
    private Date dateFin ; 
    private double nombreSemaines ; 
    private String EtatPeriode ;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="PeriodeLocation")
    private List<Location> locations ;


    public PerieodeLocation(Long numPeriode, Long referenceLocation,
            Date dateDebut, Date dateFin, double nombreSemaines,
            String etatPeriode, List<Location> locations) {
        super();
        this.numPeriode = numPeriode;
        ReferenceLocation = referenceLocation;
        this.dateDebut = dateDebut;
        this.dateFin = dateFin;
        this.nombreSemaines = nombreSemaines;
        EtatPeriode = etatPeriode;
        this.locations = locations;
    }
    public List<Location> getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }
    public void setLocations(List<Location> locations) {
        this.locations = locations;
    }
    public PerieodeLocation() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Long getNumPeriode() {
        return numPeriode;
    }
    public void setNumPeriode(Long numPeriode) {
        this.numPeriode = numPeriode;
    }
    public Long getReferenceLocation() {
        return ReferenceLocation;
    }
    public void setReferenceLocation(Long referenceLocation) {
        ReferenceLocation = referenceLocation;
    }
    public Date getDateDebut() {
        return dateDebut;
    }
    public void setDateDebut(Date dateDebut) {
        this.dateDebut = dateDebut;
    }
    public Date getDateFin() {
        return dateFin;
    }
    public void setDateFin(Date dateFin) {
        this.dateFin = dateFin;
    }
    public double getNombreSemaines() {
        return nombreSemaines;
    }
    public void setNombreSemaines(double nombreSemaines) {
        this.nombreSemaines = nombreSemaines;
    }
    public String getEtatPeriode() {
        return EtatPeriode;
    }
    public void setEtatPeriode(String etatPeriode) {
        EtatPeriode = etatPeriode;
    }
```

}

when i execute the app it returns this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.agence.AgenceTouristique2Application.main(AgenceTouristique2Application.java:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:860) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.agence.entitises.Location.PeriodeLocation in com.agence.entitises.PerieodeLocation.locations
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:769) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:729) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    ... 24 common frames omitted

2016-05-10 20:40:18.330  INFO 3148 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/Lemin/workspace/AgenceTouristique2/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.5/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.5/logback-core-1.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.16/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.16/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.8/aspectjweaver-1.8.8.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.32/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.32/tomcat-juli-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.4.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.16/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.5/jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.5/jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.5/jackson-core-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Lemin/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.0/scala-library-2.11.0.jar]
```

please anyhelp i have to handle this exception

Comment: Replace `mappedBy="Contrats"` with `mappedBy="contrats"` and also, `mappedBy="PeriodeLocation"` with `mappedBy="periodeLocation"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can someone please explain mappedBy in hibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108224/can-someone-please-explain-mappedby-in-hibernate)