# How to persist a property of type List<List<Object>> in JPA?

Tags: list, spring-boot, entity

What is the smartest way to get an entity with a field of type List<List> persisted?

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "Final_Feign_Client_Result")
public class FinalFCResultEntity {

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@ElementCollection(targetClass = Object.class)
@CollectionTable(name = "Final_Feign_Client_Result_Columns")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JoinColumn(name = "final_feign_client_result_entity_id", nullable = false)
private Set<Object> values;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Set<Object> getValues() {
    return values;
}

public void setValues(Set<Object> values) {
    this.values = values;
}
```

}
I have no problem with columns, but if I try to insert values I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: final_feign_client_result_columns, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(values)]
```

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hi guidop21 please add

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Object.class)
@CollectionTable(name = "Final_Feign_Client_Result_Columns")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JoinColumn(name = "final_feign_client_result_entity_id", nullable = false)
@OneToMany
private List<List<<Object>> values;
```

Comment: The getter and setter methods are already present in the class but that doesn't change

Comment: I made the change you suggested but nothing has changed

Comment: I will hell the problem, if it is not the damage, look it

Comment: Now this exception appears: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: collection element mapping has wrong number of columns: com.nttdata.iot.simplemicroservice.database.entity.FinalFCResultEntity.values type: object

Comment: add List<List<Object>> @OneToMany anotation

Comment: sorry can you write in your answer the variable with all its annotations please?

Comment: guidop21 I am editing answer pleaese check

Comment: NOW: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.nttdata.iot.simplemicroservice.database.entity.FinalFCResultEntity.values[java.util.List]...Thanks for your help

Comment: not working please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769440/how-to-map-a-list-of-objects-into-a-table-with-hibernate-in-spring

Comment: The main problem is that they don't like the Object type. Do you know a way to cast from Set <Object> to Set <String> or List <List <Object>> to List <List <String>>, because in my model class FinalFCResultModel I have to use the Object type