# Hibernate: Specifying correct value for mappedBy attribute for composite PK, FK

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I am trying to understand OneToOne mapping between two Entities.

I am not able to understand how to specify the `mappedBy` attribute in `OneToOne` for making it bi-directional relation.

## UserID embeddable type:

```
@Embeddable
public class UserID  implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int ssnID;
    private int uniqueNum;
    // getters and setters..
}
```

## VehicleID embeddable type:

```
@Embeddable
public class VehicleID implements Serializable {
    private int vehicleID;
    private int regNum;
    // getters and setters
}
```

## Vehicle Entity having composite primary key VehicleID:

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle {

    @EmbeddedId
    private VehicleID vehicleID;
    private String description;
    // getters and setters..
}
```

## UserInfo Entity having composite priamary key UserID  and is owning-side entity for OneToOne relationship between UserInfo and Vehicle:

```
@Entity
public class UserInfo {
    private String full_name;
    @EmbeddedId
    UserID userID;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="vehicle_ID") , @JoinColumn(name="reg_Num")}) // Composite primary key in Vehicle
    Vehicle veh;
    // getters, setters and other code
}
```

`UserInfo` is the owning-side entity and having `OneToOne` relationship with `Vehicle` entity (which has composite VehicleID as primary key).

## My doubt is here:

In `UserInfo` entity, we specify the `OneToOne` relationship (and the annotations):

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="vehicle_ID") , @JoinColumn(name="reg_Num")})
Vehicle veh;
```

As can be seen above that in `UserInfo` table, we are having a composite foreign key on `Vehicle` table, and name of the `JoinColumn` specifying as `vehicle_ID` and `reg_Num`.

Now, when I want to make it bi-directional relation we need to use the `mappedBy` attribute, and it is that where I am not able to understand what property to refer.

```
@Ent/ity
public class Vehicle {
    @EmbeddedId
    private VehicleID vehicleID;
    private String description;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="UserID")
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    // getters and setters..
}
```

I kept "UserID" as it is "composite" primary key for UserInfo, but it is throwing exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown
>   mappedBy in: com.example.entity.Vehicle.userInfo, referenced property
>   unknown: com.example.entity.UserInfo.UserID

I am not able to understand what property to refer here; the examples which i have seen in tutorials, most of them have a single PK, FK; but in my case it is composite PK, FK.

Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: It should be `@OneToOne(mappedBy="veh")`

Comment: @HadiJeddizahed: It works, but could you elaborate a bit on this? I still don't understand this.

Comment: The `mappedBy` element identifies the inverse side of a relationship. here you have relation between `Vehicle` and `UserInfo` so to identify inverse side of relation should using it by other side property. here `veh`. sorry for bad explaining :( see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108224/can-someone-please-explain-mappedby-in-hibernate)

Comment: @HadiJeddizahed Please don't write answers in the comments. Can you please post this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="veh")
private UserInfo userInfo;
```

The `mappedBy` element identifies the inverse side of a relationship. here you have relation between Vehicle and UserInfo so to identify inverse side of relation should using it by other side property. here `veh`.

for more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108224/can-someone-please-explain-mappedby-in-hibernate)