# Hibernate - OneToMany retrieving only one row

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, one-to-many

I have the following class which has a `@OneToMany` relationship, but it only returns one of the two rows:

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "as_itm_ext")
public class ItemExtensionEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "id_itm", referencedColumnName = "id_itm", insertable = false, updatable = false) })
    public Set<ItemAttributeEntity> getItemAttributeEntities() {
        return this.itemAttributeEntities;
    }

    public void setItemAttributeEntities(Set<ItemAttributeEntity> itemAttributeEntities) {
        this.itemAttributeEntities = itemAttributeEntities;
    }
}
```

And the class to be retrieved:

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "as_itm_att")
public class ItemAttributeEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * AttributeKey,The key of the attribute.
     */
    private ItemAttributeEntityId id;

    /**
     * AttributeValue,The value of the attribute.
     */
    private String attributeValue;

    public ItemAttributeEntity() {
    }

    public ItemAttributeEntity(ItemAttributeEntityId id, String attributeValue) {
        this.id = id;
        this.attributeValue = attributeValue;
    }

    /**
     * AttributeKey,The key of the attribute.
     */
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "itemId", column = @Column(name = "id_itm", nullable = false, length = 32)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "attributeKey", column = @Column(name = "att_key", nullable = false, length = 32)) })
    public ItemAttributeEntityId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(ItemAttributeEntityId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * AttributeValue,The value of the attribute.
     */
    @Column(name = "att_value", nullable = false, length = 32)
    public String getAttributeValue() {
        return this.attributeValue;
    }

    public void setAttributeValue(String attributeValue) {
        this.attributeValue = attributeValue;
    }

}
```

I already tried to change the `Set` to `List` but no luck (and after reading a bit about the differences between them it make no sense to change it).

I have no clue of what is happening, and not sure if it always worked like that.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: Tried implementing `equals`, nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use *fetch = FetchType.LAZY* on *itemAttributeEntities*.

Comment: In case of eager loading of subcollection hibernate do sql with join of two tables (main table and table of subcollection objects) and not very correct processes sql's resultset

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you need to add reference(as @ManyToOne) of `ItemExtensionEntity` in your `ItemAttributeEntity` class and 
Add mappedby attribute inside @OneToMany annotation on your Entity `ItemExtensionEntity`

Reference: [Can someone please explain mappedBy in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108224/can-someone-please-explain-mappedby-in-hibernate#answer-9108623)

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "as_itm_ext")
public class ItemExtensionEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentEntity" ,fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    //@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "id_itm", referencedColumnName = "id_itm", insertable = false, updatable = false) })
    public Set<ItemAttributeEntity> getItemAttributeEntities() {
        return this.itemAttributeEntities;
    }

    public void setItemAttributeEntities(Set<ItemAttributeEntity> itemAttributeEntities) {
        this.itemAttributeEntities = itemAttributeEntities;
    }
}


@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "as_itm_att")
public class ItemAttributeEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * AttributeKey,The key of the attribute.
     */
    private ItemAttributeEntityId id;

    /**
     * AttributeValue,The value of the attribute.
     */
    private String attributeValue;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="<columnname>", nullable=false)
    private ItemExtensionEntity parentEntity;

    //add getter and setters

    public ItemAttributeEntity() {
    }

    public ItemAttributeEntity(ItemAttributeEntityId id, String attributeValue) {
        this.id = id;
        this.attributeValue = attributeValue;
    }

    /**
     * AttributeKey,The key of the attribute.
     */
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "itemId", column = @Column(name = "id_itm", nullable = false, length = 32)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "attributeKey", column = @Column(name = "att_key", nullable = false, length = 32)) })
    public ItemAttributeEntityId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(ItemAttributeEntityId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * AttributeValue,The value of the attribute.
     */
    @Column(name = "att_value", nullable = false, length = 32)
    public String getAttributeValue() {
        return this.attributeValue;
    }

    public void setAttributeValue(String attributeValue) {
        this.attributeValue = attributeValue;
    }

}
```