# How can I solve this Spring UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, hibernate-mapping

I just started learning Spring and Hibernate and I was trying to do some practice, but I met some problems. The basic structure is sample, like this. [image]

However, I met a problem with UnsatisfiedDependencyException:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'administratorController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-school-management-sys-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.demo.schoolmanagementsystem.entity.Users.users in com.demo.schoolmanagementsystem.entity.Institution.users
```

The code I have done is in this Link: https://github.com/LehTia/schoolmanagementsystem. I had looked it all day but I could not find it. Can anyone take a quick look what I had done and tell me where went wrong?

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with mappedBy property, you set property "users" which is not correct. In your case you should use:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy="institution",
            cascade={CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
private List<Users> users;
```

Even you are making the relation between two tables only one of those tables has a foreign key constraint to the other one. 
"MappedBy allows you to still link from the table not containing the constraint to the other table."
Please read [Can someone please explain mappedBy in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108224/can-someone-please-explain-mappedby-in-hibernate) and http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many

Comment: wow. This was really a bad mistake done by me. Thx for getting me out of this.