# How to POST oneToMany relational database entries with Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

How should I structure a JSON POST, the controller on my backend, and the POJO classes?

This is for a twitter clone, so a user can have multiple tweets etc

POST

`{
    "tweet": "Sew one button, doesn't make u a tailor",
    "user": "Alex"
}`

Tweet Controller

```
    public Tweet createTweet(@RequestBody Tweet tweet) {
        return tweetRepository.save(tweet);
    }
```

Tweet Class

```
@Table(name = "tweets")
public class Tweet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private User user;

    ...
```

User Class

```
@Table(name = "custom_user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tweet_id")
    private List<Tweet> tweet = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is the response I'm getting

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Alex",
        "tweet": []
    },
    "tweet": "Sew one button, doesn't make u a tailor"
}
```

edit:

If I do a GET on my users endpoint, this is what I get (there should be associated tweets included)

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Alex",
        "tweet": []
    }
]
```

Comment: what do you mean by structure a JSON Post? a post to your endpoint? or a post where? you have already a json format in the example you gave

Comment: A POST to my endpoint yes, that is what I have so far, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: did you try it? it looks fine, as long as it is a valid tweet model, your app should process it same way

Comment: Why is that tweet not populating in the reponse though? Like nested in the user property?

Comment: have you debugged and see tweet is not null when you reach tweetRepository.save(tweet);? you can even make a println if you dont have a good ide to debug. is it null?

Comment: @HahnSolo did the solution I gave work for you? If it did, please consider marking it as best answer for future reference.

Comment: @GabrielPimenta yes it did. I ended up using JsonBackReference and JsonManagedReference as well to handle the infinite recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Alex",
        "tweet": []
    },
    "tweet": "Sew one button, doesn't make u a tailor"
}
```

By the looks of it, your Tweet object has a tweet attribute, and your User object has an array that maps every tweet related to that user, that is currently empty on the example.

It looks to me like a problem on your bidirectional mapping between Tweet and User. Consider using the [mappedBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108224/can-someone-explain-mappedby-in-hibernate) property on bidirectional relationships.