# placement of mappedBy in a OneToOne relationship in Java Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

If we have two classes X and Y that have OneToOne relationship between them

```java
class A {
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = a)
  private B b;
}
class B {
  @OneToOne
  private A a;
}
```

I would like to know if it makes any difference if we method the `mappedBy` from Class A to Class B..

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108224/can-someone-explain-mappedby-in-jpa-and-hibernate

Comment: Your question is unclear. what do you mean `if we method the mappedBy from Class A to Class B`

Answer (score 1):

When you both entities (A and B) you can choose one that will have a foreign key.

In your example, the `foreign key` will be in B, referencing A.

But in A, you want referencing B. So, you say to the JPA: I have this `class A` with a relationship with B, but it was created in B. So `mappedBy` is just a reverse reference to get B in this relationship.

```java
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "a")
```